# Plesk Onyx & Nextcloud PHP Errors

Tags: php, plesk, php-extension, nextcloud, plesk-onyx

I tried to install Nextcloud 13 in Plesk, but if I try to open the link I get a HTTP 500 error.

PHP version: 7.0.27

PHP modules: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Sk0.png)

php_error.log: too long (I can send the pastebin link)

Please tell me if you need more info. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you also post your php_error.log link?

Answer (score 0):

You might have set the wrong file permission on your Nextcloud installation.
If you created the Nextcloud directory with root permission, you need to change the ownership of the directory to a user or a group, that Plesk has permissions for.

---

Use these commands to change the ownership (replace **myPleskUser** with the username you specified during the Plesk installation)

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.tld/
chown -R myPleskUser ./nextcloud
chgrp -R psaserv ./nextcloud
```